# Riley's Favorite Toys!

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

> My whole is a tinkers' toymaker.
>
> As is my middle.
>
> My first is some parts of a train network.
>
> And my last affixes them together.

What am I?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are

> HASBRO?

My whole is a tinkers' toymaker.

> HASBRO is the current producer of Tinker Toys.
>  [image: tinkertoys]

As is my middle.

> "AS" is literally your middle.

My first is some parts of a train network.

> 'H' is a common name for a rail line, and Wikipedia also lists 3 rail networks named ["H"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_(disambiguation)) in the 'Other Uses' section - for example *H, Rockaway Park Shuttle subway service in New York*.

And my last affixes them together.

> Your BRO (brother) perhaps really enjoys tinker toys and puts them together with you.

What am I?

> First + Middle + Last = Whole = HASBRO!

Title:

> The favorite toys of you and your brother could be Tinkertoys, produced by HASBRO.

Comment: Good attempt, but none of these elements are right. The answer for the train clue is not an arbitrarily lettered line.